# How to impove the speed of tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset in tensorflow 1.13.1?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow-datasets

I am coding a toy example for csv data in Tensorflow. 
I have implemented three types of data loader in tensorflow and pytorch to compare their speeds. Here is the code:

First, with tensorflow api `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`:

```
def parse_data(x, n_classes):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    return x[:-1], tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(x[-1], tf.int32), depth=n_classes)

if __name__=='__main__':
    dataset_train = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset('/home/david/Dataset/timit/test.csv', [tf.float32] * 430,
                                                    header=False,
                                                    field_delim=' ')
    dataset_train = dataset_train.map(lambda *x_: parse_data(x_, 1928))
    dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(128)
    dataset_train = dataset_train.prefetch(1)
    iterator = dataset_train.make_initializable_iterator()

    x_in, y = iterator.get_next()

    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x_in)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    logits = tf.layers.Dense(units=1928, activation=None)(x)

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y, logits)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    optimizer.minimize(loss)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    running_loss = 0.0
    time_last = time.time()
    epoch = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            running_loss += sess.run(loss)  # , feed_dict={x: data, y: labels})
            if (i + 1) % 5 == 0:
                print('\r[epoch: %2d, batch: %5d, time: %5f] loss: %.3f' % (
                    epoch + 1, i + 1, time.time() - time_last, running_loss / i), end=' ')
                time_last = time.time()
            i += 1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
```

Second, using `pandas` and `tf.placeholder`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_in = tf.placeholder(shape=[128, 429], dtype=tf.float32)
    y_in = tf.placeholder(shape=[128], dtype=tf.int32)
    y = tf.one_hot(y_in, depth=1928)

    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x_in)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = tf.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    logits = tf.layers.Dense(units=1928, activation=None)(x)

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y, logits)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    optimizer.minimize(loss)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    w = pd.read_csv('/home/david/Dataset/timit/test.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True).values

    for epoch in range(23):
        running_loss = 0.0
        time_last = time.time()
        i = 0
        indexes = np.random.permutation(w.shape[0])
        w_ = w[indexes, :]
        while True:
            if i * 128 + 128 > w.shape[0]:
                break
            running_loss += sess.run(loss,
                                     feed_dict={x_in: w_[i * 128:i * 128 + 128, :-1],
                                                y_in: w_[i * 128:i * 128 + 128, -1]})
            if (i + 1) % 5 == 0:
                print('\r[epoch: %2d, batch: %5d, time: %5f] loss: %.3f' % (
                    epoch + 1, i + 1, time.time() - time_last, running_loss / i), end=' ')
                time_last = time.time()
            i += 1
```

Third, with `pytorch` and `pandas`:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(429, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(1024, 1928)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x


class CsvDataset(data.Dataset):
    """Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.values[idx, :]
        return landmarks[:-1], landmarks[-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Net()
    device = torch.device('cuda:0')
    print(device)
    net.to(device)

    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    dataset = CsvDataset('/home/david/Dataset/timit/train.csv')
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)

    for epoch in range(23):

        running_loss = 0.0
        time_last = time.time()
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
            inputs, labels = data
            inputs = inputs.float().to(device)
            labels = labels.long().to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            output = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(output, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()
            if (i + 1) % 5 == 0:
                print('\r[epoch: %2d, batch: %5d, time: %5f] loss: %.3f' % (
                    epoch + 1, i + 1, time.time() - time_last, running_loss / i), end=' ')
                time_last = time.time()
        print('')
    print('Finished Training')
```

I record the time cost for training in five batches:

- First, CsvDataset: 1.382647s
- Second, tf.placeholder: 0.013263s
- Third, pytorch: 0.042086s

I guess it is partly because that `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` do io operations before each batch to extract data from csv file (Is this ture, or there are other reasons?).

However, it is too slow comparing to the other two. Is there any chance for improvement? How can I set the `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` api to load all csv data at the very beginning?

Or can I say that `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` is implemented only for the csv dataset that is too big to store in the memory? Because the time cost seems like intolerable.

Comment: What is the start initial learning rate in the second case?

Comment: @prosti it has default lr Parma’s

Comment: How big is your CSV file?

Comment: @prosti about 50000 instances, 429 features

Comment: Instances you mean rows, and features you mean columns?

Comment: @prosti no, I just used the toy example to test training time

Comment: why you have `[tf.float32] * 430` when 429 features (columns) I assume all with float values?

Comment: @prosti the last column is labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may play with the batch size in the first example, and if it reads batches from file every time you can prove it if you make it 2x bigger, you may expect 2x speed improvement. I haven't played with (experimental) class `CsvDataset`  in TF.

I am sure Pandas reads your document faster and this is part of the reason why you have these times.

Probable the next step you should unset the loss function `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. Most probable have the regression problem and not the classification problem judging by float labels you have at the end.

So try `torch.nn.MSELoss` as the loss function.

Comment: Hi, I tried to double batches and the time cost of ```CsvDataset``` of each batch doubles (about 2.6s). While the second with ```tf.placeholder``` still needs about 0.013s  (the computation cost does not change so much as the batch_size grows). So I think it is caused by IO operations. I am still surprised that the api ```CsvDataset``` is so slow, but I cannot find errors in the above coding.

Comment: IO, and print functions should be the major time consumers. I am not surprised with `CsvDataset` speed, it is experimental, they just wanted to prove the concept.