# How to stream a multi-file (b, t, f)-shaped data into Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I have a large data which I want to load into a Tensorflow Dataset in order to train a LSTM net. I want to use streaming functionality rather than reading the whole data into memory due to the size of my data. I am struggling with reading my data so that each sample *i* is properly shaped as *(t<sub>i</sub>, m)*.

Sample code to replicate:

```
# One hundred samples, each with three features
# Second dim is time-steps for each sample. I will
# randomize this in a step below
x = np.random.randn(100,10,3)
# One hundred {0,1} labels
y = (np.random.rand(100)>0.5)*1
y=y.reshape((-1,1))

# Save each sample in its own file
for i in range(len(x)):
  cat = y[i][0]
  data = x[i]
  # Simulate random length of each sample
  data = data[:np.random.randint(4,10),:]
  fname = 'tmp_csv/{:.0f}/{:03.0f}.csv'.format(cat,i)
  np.savetxt(fname, data, delimiter=',')
```

Now I have one hundred csv files, each with a single sample of size *(t<sub>i</sub>, 3)*. How can I read these files back into a Tensorflow Dataset while maintaining the shape for each sample?

I tried serialization (but didn't know how to do it properly), flattening so that each sample is in one row (but didn't know how to handle variable row size and how to reshape), and I tried vanilla `make_csv_dataset`. Here is my `make_csv_dataset` attempt:

```
ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
  file_pattern = "tmp_csv/*/*.csv",
  batch_size=10, num_epochs=1,
  num_parallel_reads=5,
  shuffle_buffer_size=10,
  header=False,
  column_names=['a','b','c']
)

for i in ds.take(1):
  print(i)
```

...but this results in each sample being of shape (1,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `make_csv_dataset` is interpreting every row in each `csv` file as one sample. You could try something like this, but I am not sure how efficient it is for your use case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# One hundred samples, each with three features
# Second dim is time-steps for each sample. I will
# randomize this in a step below
x = np.random.randn(100,10,3)
# One hundred {0,1} labels
y = (np.random.rand(100)>0.5)*1
y=y.reshape((-1,1))

# Save each sample in its own file
for i in range(len(x)):
  cat = y[i][0]
  data = x[i]
  # Simulate random length of each sample
  data = data[:np.random.randint(4,10),:]
  fname = 'tmp_csv/{:.0f}{:03.0f}.csv'.format(cat,i)
  np.savetxt(fname, data, delimiter=',')

def columns_to_tensor(data_from_one_csv):
  ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
  for i, t in enumerate(data_from_one_csv):
    ta = ta.write(tf.cast(i, dtype=tf.int32), tf.stack([t[0], t[1], t[2]], axis=0))
  return ta.stack()

files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("tmp_csv/*.csv")
ds = files.map(lambda file: tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(file, record_defaults=[tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32], header=False))
ds = ds.map(columns_to_tensor)
for i,j in enumerate(ds):
  print(i, j.shape)
```

```
0 (5, 3)
1 (9, 3)
2 (5, 3)
3 (6, 3)
4 (8, 3)
5 (7, 3)
6 (6, 3)
7 (8, 3)
8 (8, 3)
9 (7, 3)
10 (9, 3)
11 (9, 3)
12 (7, 3)
13 (9, 3)
14 (4, 3)
15 (5, 3)
16 (6, 3)
17 (6, 3)
18 (8, 3)
19 (8, 3)
20 (8, 3)
21 (9, 3)
22 (9, 3)
23 (7, 3)
24 (8, 3)
25 (8, 3)
26 (5, 3)
27 (7, 3)
28 (5, 3)
29 (8, 3)
30 (9, 3)
31 (6, 3)
32 (6, 3)
33 (7, 3)
34 (6, 3)
35 (9, 3)
36 (9, 3)
37 (5, 3)
38 (9, 3)
39 (9, 3)
40 (7, 3)
41 (7, 3)
42 (7, 3)
43 (6, 3)
44 (9, 3)
45 (4, 3)
46 (9, 3)
47 (6, 3)
48 (9, 3)
49 (8, 3)
50 (7, 3)
51 (4, 3)
52 (4, 3)
53 (6, 3)
54 (7, 3)
55 (7, 3)
56 (9, 3)
57 (7, 3)
58 (5, 3)
59 (7, 3)
60 (8, 3)
61 (8, 3)
62 (5, 3)
63 (5, 3)
64 (7, 3)
65 (6, 3)
66 (6, 3)
67 (7, 3)
68 (6, 3)
69 (9, 3)
70 (5, 3)
71 (4, 3)
72 (8, 3)
73 (8, 3)
74 (6, 3)
75 (7, 3)
76 (9, 3)
77 (6, 3)
78 (5, 3)
79 (7, 3)
80 (6, 3)
81 (5, 3)
82 (4, 3)
83 (5, 3)
84 (4, 3)
85 (5, 3)
86 (4, 3)
87 (4, 3)
88 (7, 3)
89 (5, 3)
90 (4, 3)
91 (7, 3)
92 (4, 3)
93 (7, 3)
94 (4, 3)
95 (5, 3)
96 (6, 3)
97 (6, 3)
98 (7, 3)
99 (9, 3)
```

Afterwards, just call `ds.batch` with your desired batch size.

Comment: thank you! Yeah it is a little slow but it does work... Any thoughts on making it more efficient?

Comment: Increase the batch size, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714388/how-to-impove-the-speed-of-tf-data-experimental-csvdataset-in-tensorflow-1-13-1, but in your case it is difficult to have a large batch size since you have various timesteps for each sample. You could consider padding them and then you will be able to use any batch size you want.

Comment: I see thank you. I can also do prefetching to eliminate that lag. I think this will do, thank you @Alone.